# How should I work around a particular "chicken and egg" problem with entity construction?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, efcore

I'm struggling to think of a concise way to phrase the question, but assume you were developing an application that managed employees at various company branches. You could potentially model this part of the application like this:

[image: branch and employees example]

It's stipulated that every employee must belong to exactly one branch. To enforce this, you'd pass the branch the employee operates at to the `Employee` constructor and make the corresponding property immutable:

```
class Employee {

    public Employee(int id, string name, Branch operatesAt)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        OperatesAt = operatesAt;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Branch OperatesAt { get; }
}
```

You might then choose to model the `Branch` class like this:

```
class Branch {

    private readonly List<Employee> _employees;

    public Branch(int id, string name, ICollection<Employee> employees)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        _employees = employees.ToList();
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Employee> Employees => _employees.AsReadOnly();
}
```

In my application I'm using EF Core, and something similar to these models would work fine. I'm following [Microsoft's architectural recommendations for ASP.NET Core development](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/), and as such I'm trying to use a domain-driven approach to modelling the entities that EF Core operates with. This is why I'm trying to use constructors to ensure my entities can only ever exist in a valid state and prevent mutation of these entities except through methods that represent domain-relevant operations.

However, trying to manually setup a new branch with employees (for example, in tests) exposes a chicken and the egg problem:

```
var branch = new Branch(id: 1, name: "Example branch", employees: new[]
{
    new ProductConsultant(id: 12345, name: "John Smith", operatesAt: um...)
});
```

Is this a common issue to run into, and if so is there a well-defined solution to it? Someone I discussed this with mentioned the builder pattern could work. An alternative that I'm thinking of going with is to define a factory method on the principal entity that constructs, registers and returns an instance of the dependent entity:

```
class Branch {

    private readonly List<Employee> _employees;

    public Branch(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        _employees = new List<Employee>();    
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Employee> Employees => _employees.AsReadOnly();

    public Employee RegisterNewEmployee(int id, string name)
    {
        var employee = new Employee(id, name, this);
        _employees.Add(employee);
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Is this a suitable approach, or is there something more appropriate that can be done here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with EF so forgive my innocence... but why can't you create a branch without employees and then add the employees immediately afterwards?

Comment: @JacobRaihle That's what I'm proposing with my solution at the bottom. It should all work, I'm just wondering if there's any other alternatives that I haven't thought of.

Comment: Can you explain why a branch needs a list of Employees? Is there a functional requirement why you need that information inside branch?

Comment: @RikD Currently there isn't, but the next vertical slice of functionality I'm implementing requires me to model an operation on `Branch` that performs logic involving all of its employees, and so the branch needs to know what employees operate at it.

Comment: Is it that the branch _has_ employees or that the branch _owns_ employees?  One is simply an association between independently viable entities, the other controls the _lifetime_ of the entities.  Perhaps the model you describe in inappropriate so that your question about how to construct these things in premature.

Comment: @davidbak It's an associative rather than compositional relationship; branches have employees, and employees may be reassigned between branches.

Comment: @Tagc - yes, exactly.  So you have no problem: Employees are independent entities from branches, they have a lifetime that is _unrelated_ to a branch's lifetime.  You create an Employee whenever you want, delete it whenever you want, same for Branches.  Then you _associate_ them (or disassociate them) whenever you want.  Design your API with that in mind.

Comment: @davidbak I'll include methods to allow employees to be reassigned down the line, but I believe I ought to be preserving the invariant that an employee must *always* be assigned to a branch. To do this I think I need to prevent construction of an employee object unless there's a branch it can be assigned to on construction.

Comment: @Tagc you know your domain / use cases best and should go by that, but usually when modeling this problem there is no such invariant.  In real life in most similar domains some employees are on leave, or work remotely, etc.  There is also frequently a need to retain an employee record after the person has left employment.  Separately from real life, there is no need to _model_ the invariant statically via a structure or enforce it _statically_ via an API.  You can provide enforcement at run time by checking constraints and issuing errors.  That's just as valid, maybe more useful.

Comment: @davidbak That's true, but to keep this question broad for accessibility's sake (perhaps more than I ought to have done), I'm presenting a pretty loosely-defined "employee" context for this question. In my actual app, I'm dealing with a specific type of employee (car salesmen) and within a specific domain of the business (managing commissions). These sales people never work remotely, and for all intents are always assigned to one branch (another system in our department acts as the source of truth for that). When they leave, they cease to exist as far as the commissions domain is concerned.

Comment: All that said, there might be merit in preserving the invariants at runtime instead of forcing it through the code structure. I'll probably be able to get better idea further down the line.

Answer (score 8):

```
var branch = new Branch(id: 1, name: "Example branch", employees: new[]
{
    new ProductConsultant(id: 12345, name: "John Smith", operatesAt: um...)
});
```

This particular chicken and egg problem suggests that your design is inappropriate for the problem.

The key idea is that "an employee belongs to a branch" is a description of a relationship between some representation of employee and some representation of branch,  but it doesn't say that employee has-a branch, in the data composition sense.

Consider

```
class Employee {

    public Employee(int id, string name, int operatesAt)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        OperatesAt = operatesAt;
    }
```

which is to say, we bind the employee to branch identifier, rather than the branch itself.

Now your test can be written fairly easily:

```
var branch = new Branch(id: 1, name: "Example branch", employees: new[]
{
    new ProductConsultant(id: 12345, name: "John Smith", operatesAt: 1)
});
```

You can also play the same game in reverse, if you like:

```
var consultant = new ProductConsultant(id: 12345, name: "John Smith", operatesAt: 1)
var branch = new Branch(id: 1, name: "Example branch", employees: new[] { 12345 })
```

Other possibilities include treating the relationship between employee and branch as an entity in its own right, with its own lifecycle:

```
var assignment = new OfficeAssignment(employee:12345, branch: 1)
```

"It depends" is an Important Truth of domain driven design; we tend to employ these techniques in business critical parts of the domain, which implies that there is payoff in getting the small details right.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback. In the past I've considered only passing the branch ID to the constructor rather than the entire branch model, but for some operations the branch model itself needs to be accessible from the employee. For example, when responding to queries about an employee, I return the branch name as part of the employee read model.

Comment: `For example, when responding to queries about an employee, I return the branch name as part of the employee read model` yes, but when you do queries about employees, somehow you have to retrieve the branch info too. Doesn't matter if an ERM does it or you do it from a loop (iterating employees). in both cases, there will be several queries to the datastore (performance is not an argument). On the other and, nothing prevents you from implementing a "representation" of Employee with branch name, which is to say, you can have different DTOs to represent the same thing,

Answer (score 4):

I'd seriously question the "Employee must have a branch" philosophy.

- Does someone who works from home have a branch?
- What if they literally drive around all day?
- What about the Area Manager, presumably they work across a few branches.
- And what about call center staff? Calling their office a branch starts to stretch the definition of branch, are warehouses branches too?

The problem is that employee's are not weak entities. They exist regardless of their being a branch. It is simply the flavour of the day that management has decided that every employee be associated with a branch.

In fact this is very similar to the problem from [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/). Whatever you hard code now will need rewriting later when requirements change: such as needing to write unit tests, or talking about employees without caring about branches. I wouldn't go so far as to implement a full blown ECS, but the point is to separate the different shearing levels so that they are easier to change.

First step would be to separate the `Employee` out into roles, aka `interfaces`. This way code that tangentially needs an employee for some reason can be passed a mock implementing just the expected interface. That code might not even care about branches.

Second step would be to treat `Employee` (assuming you still are implementing all those interfaces on one concrete implementation) as a strong entity on its own merits. That would mean that `Employee` does not require a `Branch` object to be constructed, a `BranchId` would be enough. Similarly for `Branch` except this time a list of `EmployeeID`s are enough.

Third step is to see if you cannot tease apart `Employee` into seperate concrete classes implementing fewer interfaces. Chances are the software contains several perspectives on what an `Employee` is and only cares about one perspective or another for large tranches of work.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong solution for the problem at hand.

> It's stipulated that every employee must belong to exactly one branch.

> To enforce this, you'd pass the branch the employee operates at to the Employee constructor and make the corresponding property immutable:

This is not correct. The proposed solution solves a completely different problem, unrelated to your actual problem.

---

### Your actual problem

> It's stipulated that every employee must belong to exactly one branch.

You don't need to restrict the property or make it readonly. The simplest way to comply with this rule is dead simple:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}
```

When the `Employee` class has a `Branch` property (i.e. **not** a collection of branches such as `Branch[]` or `IEnumerable<Branch>`), then each employee can only belong to one branch. You can change which branch they belong to, but they can never belong to more than one branch.

Basically, if there's only one chair in the room, only one person can sit. Since there's only one property that can contain one `Branch` object, therefore the `Employee` can only belong to one `Branch` (i.e. the one you set it to).

---

### Your proposed solution

> To enforce this, you'd pass the branch the employee operates at to the Employee constructor and make the corresponding property immutable:

Think about what your implementation does. The implementation consists of two parts: the constructor parameter, and the readonly nature of the property (post-constructor, if you will).

In terms of **readonly**, the only thing you're achieving is that an employee's branch cannot be changed after it has been set. That's it. But since you never mention this as a requirement, it's simply not necessary.

In terms of **constructor parameter**, what does it achieve for you? Likely, you're going to say that "this forces the consumer to pass the branch", but if your constructor merely assigns the parameter to your property, which yours does, it doesn't actually protect against anything.
The same default value for `Branch` that you'd get with an uninitialized property (that's *not* in the constructor) could effectively be passed via the constructor anyway. It's not blocking that behavior, so you're not really adding value.

The only thing you're doing here is creating more hoops for your consumer to jump through, without actually solving the issue you want solved.

---

### Chicken and egg

> However, trying to manually setup a new branch with employees (for example, in tests) exposes a chicken and the egg problem:

```
var branch = new Branch(id: 1, name: "Example branch", employees: new[]
{
    new ProductConsultant(id: 12345, name: "John Smith", operatesAt: um...)
});
```

Notice how the problem goes away when you remove your `readonly` constraint:

```
var employee = new Employee() { Name = "John" };
var branch = new Branch() { Name = "Houston Division" };

employee.Branch = branch;
branch.Employees.Add(employee);
```

*This is just a simple example to show how your readonly constraint is the cause of the problem. This is not the final solution for your problem.*

---

### Entity Framework

> This is why I'm trying to use constructors to ensure my entities can only ever exist in a valid state and prevent mutation of these entities except through methods that represent domain-relevant operations.

The things you're focusing on in your question and the implementation you've sought, is a code-specific implementation. But **your focus is a predominantly moot point**, because EF fundamentally changes this concept and throws your implementation out the window.

**Entity Framework uses database modeling rules**. That is to say that your entities reflect your database structure. EF does try to give you some code-friendly frills (such as navigational properties), but first and foremost the focus should be on how you want your data to be stored.

What you've described here is a **one to many** relationship. It's not *zero or one* to many, because each employee belongs to exactly one branch.

In databases, you do not link two rows directly to one another, you use their key. Most commonly, keys are (by default) expressed with **non-nullable types** such as `int` or `Guid`. I'll use `Guid` for this example. This already answers your question:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }       // Primary key

    public Guid BranchId { get; set; } // Foreign key
    public Branch Branch { get; set; } // Navigational property
}

public class Branch
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }                          // Primary key

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }  // Navigational property
}
```

This describes the one-to-many relationship, sufficiently for EF to know what to do with it. An employee has precisely one branch, and a branch can have any amount of employees.

*"And how do I configure this?"*

Entity Framework likes conventions. When you stick to its conventions, you don't actually have to manually configure much. The above entities are complete. All you need to do is add them to a db context, and EF will do what you need it to do.

If you start changing the names in my example, e.g. `Branch` to `OperatesAt`, you start edging away from the conventions. When you do that, you're going to have to configure things manually since EF cannot rely on conventional inferences anymore.

*"But what if I set `BranchId` to a value that does not exist in the branch table?"*

You'll be able to do this in code, but the moment you try to save your changes to the database, the database will throw an error. This is because EF will specifically configure the relationship using a foreign key constraint, which demands that the `BranchId` must match an existing `Id` in the branch table.

Oh, and just to complete my thought, if you never save your changes after setting the incorrect branch ID, then it won't really matter because your (incorrect) new branch ID will never reach the database and thus will never become the "truth". Since your application is database driven, the database is the source of truth, more so than your actual runtime is.

---

### Serialization and constructors

A second bit of advice that I want to give you is that serialization doesn't play nice with constructor parameters. Serialization logic tends to expect parameterless constructors, so that they can create an empty object and then set its properties one by one.

EF specifically serializes and deserializes your database data into those classes, so it's going to want parameterless constructors.

Note that *some* libraries can actually bypass this and can even instantiate types without parameterless constructors (using some clever reflection), but they do so by **bypassing** the parametered constructor, so it would still be pointless to have a parametered constructor.

---

### DDD

> I'm trying to use a domain-driven approach to modelling the entities that EF Core operates with.

Lesson one for domain-driven development: **your domain has no external dependencies**. Designing your domain *for EF Core* directly violates that lesson, since EF Core is an external dependency.

In short, because I can't explain this fully in this answer, your entities and your domain objects are two completely different layers, and they should be developed individually. It might be that one ends up looking a lot like the other, but that does not mean that you can merge them into the same class or class design.

Them looking like each other has to be a form of **coincidence**, i.e. there was no forethought or explicit intention to make them the same, they each have their own design for their own reasons and it just happens to be the same.

Secondly, in terms of how the (domain) branch and (domain) employee relate to one another, you have to consider the aggregates here. Does a branch *own* an employee, or is an employee an individual entity with its own lifetime?

In the comments, you agree that the second is more correct. If so, that means that both the employee and branch are separate aggregates (and presumably the respective aggregate roots), so you would never have such an A-in-B-in-A problem to begin with.

Working with aggregates requires more explanation than I can give here. I suggest finding online documentation on the matter to help guide your design of your aggregates and how they interact.

---

### Domain validation

This answer is too long already to elaborate on this, but you are right that even though EF enforces a FK constraint, you'd like to also have some preliminary validation (e.g. that a branch id has been set) in the domain.

This is not the place to fully elaborate on that, but definitely look up examples of DDD projects and how they implement validation.

Most commonly, this is an abstraction in and of itself that consists of more than just some restrictive domain object constructors.

As a general validation tip, be very careful about the distinction between "should not" and "cannot ever". People who don't live in my house *shouldn't* enter my house at night - but that doesn't mean that they can't. Sometimes, I might even need them to, e.g. if I'm in a medical emergency.
Just because I don't expect strangers to enter my house at night, doesn't mean that it's a good idea that I should make it absolutely impossible for anyone to enter.

Based on your proposed solution, you are trying to enforce the rule at all times - no exceptions.  But really reconsider those exceptions. Are you sure that there are *never* any exceptions? *Never?*

- What about an employee who's temporarily absent?
- What about an employee who's temporarily absent, their original department gets removed, and they have not yet been assigned a new department?
- What about partial employee data, which isn't considered complete and *should* eventually be completed, but should already be stored (in its incomplete state) in your system while awaiting completion?

These are just some examples that mean that your "no invalid data EVER" approach can be too restrictive for practical reality.

Sometimes, instead of enforcing it, you're much better off having a validation step that gets enforced selectively. For example, an employee without branch can be stored in the system (no validation check) but cannot be assigned work or be paid (doing so requires the employee to pass the validation, which includes checking that a branch was assigned).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is the one you outline. Decouple the IDs from the database.

I would question your use of Ints here though as its hard to generate unique ones. Use GUIDs, or perhaps natural ids eg. "LondonBranch" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

As for the IDs, in this case the branch IDs and employee IDs are pre-established within our company. As in, each employee at our company gets assigned an integer employee number when we join.

Answer (score 0):

You have various good answers, but none of them address the problem in the Domain Driven Design context. The thing is, you have to determine your **Aggregate Root(s)**.

If Branch is the only Aggregate Root, it could indeed contain a `RegisterNewEmployee` method. It should probably return `void`, because an Aggregate Root shouldn't expose it's internals, but it would be a good way to have a single way to create new employees. Note that in this case, you would not have an EmployeeRepository, because only Aggregate Roots should have repositories. With EF that means your DbContext should not have a DbSet for Employees.

If you decide Employee should *also* be an Aggregate Root, it's best practice that the two **Aggregate Roots only reference eachother by Id** (which is preferably a Value Object and not a primitive). That means Branch could have a collection of EmployeeIds and/or Employee could have a BranchId.

In the comments you said a Branch needs access to it's Employees. Depending on the exact requirement, a collection of Ids might suffice, for example to check for duplicates or a maximum number of Employees per branch. In case you do need access to details encapsulated in an Employee from the Branch aggregate, things get a bit ugly. You could have an `IEmployeeRepository` as an argument in the method that needs employee details, or simply pass a collection of Employees to that particular method. Anyway, that's a bit out of scope for this question.